# CS50 pset 4, Recover: program identifies >50 jpegs files

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, fopen, cs50, fread

I am currently working on the "Recover" task of the pset4 in CS50.
Firstly I need to identify some JPEG files hidden in some data given by the course saved  in card.raw.
I know card.raw contains exactly 50 JPEGs files so I initially wrote a program that aims to identify JPEGs file and then counts them. however, when I print the counter value it comes out as 860!

the first three bytes of JPEGs are: "0xff 0xd8 0xff" and the fourth byte is a hex between "0xe0" and "0xef" (the first 4 bits of the fourth byte are 1110, aka 14 in decimal)

here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Variable used for bits reading when looking for JPEGs files
int msb = 8, lsb = 4;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Find JPEG
    char *temp = malloc(3);
    int *temp1 = malloc(1);
    int counter = 0;

    while (fread(temp, 3, 1, card))
    {
        if(strcmp(temp, "0xff 0xd8 0xff"))
        {
            fread(temp1, 1, 1, card);
            int result = (*temp1 >> lsb) & ~(~0 << (msb-lsb+1));
            if(result == 14)
            {
                fseek(card, 508, SEEK_CUR);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("counter = %i\n", counter);
}
```

so in the first if:

> if(strcmp(temp, "0xff 0xd8 0xff"))

I identify if there are the first 3 bytes of the JPEG file, therefore
in the second if:

> if(result == 14)

I identify if the first 4 bits of the 4th bytes are 1110 aka 14.
it all makes sense to my head but clearly something is missing. is anyone here able to help me?

p.s. I started learning programming few weeks ago so any type of feedback is appreciated, not just related to this question. thank you :D

Comment: You really expect those specific fourteen characters and a null-terminator (i.e. the quasi string `"0xff 0xd8 0xff"`), after only reading three? And within what you allocated to have only room for three? Consider to instead compare three read bytes to three expected values.

Comment: How is `int *temp1 = malloc(1);` going to work? No room for the target type. Other people who do this task don't mess around with a partial block read, they read a whole block and identify from its first few bytes whether it is the start of a file. Then close/open the files as needed and write the block.

Comment: The `strcmp(temp, "0xff 0xd8 0xff")` is entirely wrong. This isn't a text file with those textual byte value representations. Check the bytes individuall for example `if(buff[0] == 0xFF)` etc.

Comment: And if strcmp would work equality returns 0. So you would have to have == 0 or !strcmp.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

By the course guide https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/2022/spring/psets/4/recover/, the magic value for jpeg is hexvalue 0xff 0xd8 0xff, but not string "0xff 0xd8 0xff", can you understand the differenc between them?

```
if(strcmp(temp, "0xff 0xd8 0xff"))
```

This line is wrong, you can compare the value by this method

```
int MAGIC = 0xffd8ff;
int temp;
......
......

while (fread(&temp, 3, 1, card))
{
    temp &= 0x00ffffff;
    if(temp = MAGIC)
    {
        ......
        ......
    }
}
```